# Adding gzip compression with WCF REST service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, web-services

I'm sending large data (around 600kb) from my REST web service as response. Since it takes too much time to get the response, I'm trying to compress it.

In my website, I have a generic handler. To this handler, I'm making request from my page:

```
$.getJSON('Handler.ashx', data, function (fileBytesArray) {
   // Process the data
})
.done(function () { console.log("second success"); })
.fail(function () { console.log("error"); })
.always(function () { console.log("complete"); });
```

The handler takes the request & forwards to REST service.
Handler's code:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
   HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://localhost/MyRestWebService/MyRestWebService.svc/DownloadFile"));
    req.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    req.Timeout = 60000;

    using (WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse()) 
    { 
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        string responceFromService = reader.ReadToEnd();
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        context.Response.Write(responceFromService);
    }
```

In my service (in `DownloadFile()` method), I read whole file. Then using `NewtonSoft.Json` dll, I serialize it & then return it to the handler.

Both website & REST service are on the same server. I modified `applicationHost.config` file on that server with change:

```
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
<scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"/>
<dynamicTypes>
  <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
  <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
  <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
  <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
  <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true"/>
  <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true"/>
</dynamicTypes>
<staticTypes>
  <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
  <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
  <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
  <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
  <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true"/>
  <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true"/>
</staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
```

I noticed in the `firebug` that I'm not getting any `Content Encoding` in `Response header`. Is there anything I missed?

Comment: Yeah...Here is the thing...HTTP does not support compression on the upstream. You'll have to compress using javascript and decompress on the server side in code.